# I have 2 AWS accounts A and B. On premises client network c. I have a VPN tunnel from B TO C which works fine and A TO B with peering

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I have 2 AWS accounts A and B. On premises client network c. I have a VPN tunnel from B TO C which works fine and A TO B with peering.

can we communicate from A to C with the help existing VPN tunnel from B TO C

connections i have

B to C- VPN tunnel.
A to B- AWS peering.
What i want to achieve is

A->B->C

need to be communicating A to c

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't particularly clear. You want connectivity from A to C, but you say "can we communicate from A to C with the help existing VPN tunnel from B TO C".

I can tell you the standard solutions for connecting two or more AWS accounts to a single on-premise location. AWS networks aren't transitive.

Generally I find the best way is to set up transit gateway, then attach the VPN and all AWS VPCs to the TGW. They will all be able to communicate, and it will scale to thousands of AWS accounts. Note the TGW attachment and bandwidth charges.

An alternate way in your situation is to set up another VPN from AWS Account A to on-premises C. This could be cheaper than TGW, but it won't scale easily.

A bit of a hack solution is to put some kind of a proxy server in AWS account B, A can then call C via B. This is likely to only work for limited use cases though.

Comment: if i go with VPN tunnel from A account to C .  it not required B account. Please suggest to procced

Comment: Your comment isn't very clear either. Please edit your question to clarify. It sounds like you're saying you don't need access to on-premises from AWS account B. In that case turn the VPN off and create a VPN in AWS account A.

Comment: simply i can say i have new aws account i don't want to create Site 2 site tunnel to on premsis already another AWS having site 2 site tunnel so can use that tunnel in new account to access on premsis server data.

Comment: Then Transit Gateway is likely the simplest solution for you. As I mention above, beware of the costs, but it's a useful tool. TGW is mostly used by enterprises where cost isn't the primary driver.